# python 3 threading single statement?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, python-multithreading

I am trying to create a python 3 program in which I want to display a yes or no question by `tkinter.messagebox.askyesno()` while simultaniously executing `winsound.PlaySound("SystemExclamation", winsound.SND_ALIAS)`. If I put the winsound statement first, it delays until the sound is finished playing before creating the box. If I put it after, then it plays after the user clicked yes or no, which isn't very ideal. I am only trying to thread that only statement and from what I understand `threading.Thread(target=target).start()` requires a defined function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `PlaySound` first, with [`SND_ASYNC`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/winsound#winsound.SND_ASYNC) flag:

```
winsound.PlaySound("SystemExclamation", winsound.SND_ALIAS|winsound.SND_ASYNC)
```